# The Global Assembly Cache - Deployment via Codebase Questions

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, clr, global-assembly-cache

Basically we have many severs running many ASP.NET sites in different app pools. We roll updates every 2 weeks. My basic question comes down to this:

Is using the GAC codebase feature with a URL that we maintain the latest versions of the class libraries on an independent server a good approach to simple updates of all of these sites on all of these servers?

Is there any general pitfalls or potential issues that might arise with this?

I read the Download Cache is used on a per user basis. In this case would all the sites on the server simply use the version in the ASP.NET user download cache?

Would updates occur only when a site starts? What if One site is restarted and all the other sites are using the version in the Download Cache?

Is there anyway to also manage the .aspx/.js/.css/.ascx files in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't like to trust that sort of update mechanism. It would be better to write a set of scripts, or use [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) to push the updates to the servers in a much more controlled manner.

Simon